# Nested IF statement to read and output custom date groupings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to create a nested IF statement in Excel 2016 to read a date value and output the corresponding financial month. Since a financial month is unique to the company I work for there is no available alternative other than to create a custom function or statement.

So far I have tried:

```
=IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("28/07/2017"),DATEVALUE("Jul-2017"), 
 IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("26/08/2017"),DATEVALUE("Aug-2017"), 
    IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("29/09/2017"), DATEVALUE("Sep-2017"), 
       IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("27/10/2017"), DATEVALUE("Oct-2017"), 0)))) +
          IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("24/11/2017"), DATEVALUE("Nov-2017"),
             IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("29/12/2017"), DATEVALUE("Dec-2017"),
                IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("26/01/2018"), DATEVALUE("Jan-2018"),
                   IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("23/02/2018"), DATEVALUE("Feb-2018"), 0)))) +
                      IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("20/03/2018"), DATEVALUE("Mar-2018"),
                         IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("27/04/2018"), DATEVALUE("Apr-2018"),
                            IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("25/05/2018"), DATEVALUE("May-2018"),
                               IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("29/06/2018"), DATEVALUE("Jun-2018"),
                                  IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("27/07/2018"), DATEVALUE("Jul-2018"),
                                     IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("24/08/2018"), DATEVALUE("Aug-2018"), 0)))))) +
                                        IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("28/09/2018"), DATEVALUE("Sep-2018"),
                                           IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("26/10/2018"), DATEVALUE("Oct-2018"),
                                              IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("23/11/2018"), DATEVALUE("Nov-2018"),
                                                 IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("28/12/2018"), DATEVALUE("Dec-2018"),
                                                    IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("25/01/2019"), DATEVALUE("Jan-2019"),
                                                       IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("22/02/2019"), DATEVALUE("Feb-2019"),
                                                          IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("29/03/2019"), DATEVALUE("Mar-2019"), 0))))))) +
                                                             IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("26/04/2019"), DATEVALUE("Apr-2019"), 
                                                                IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("24/05/2019"), DATEVALUE("May-2019"), 
                                                                   IF(D2 <= DATEVALUE("28/06/2019"), DATEVALUE("Jun-2019"), D2)))
```

It isn't working - I get a numeric output instead of a date.

There must be a better/effective way of doing this.

Can somebody recommend another approach? Possible via UDF in VBA?

Edit - posting a table of the ranges and required output

```
Start date  End date    Month
12/30/2017  1/26/2018   Jan-18
1/27/2018   2/23/2018   Feb-18
2/24/2018   3/30/2018   Mar-18
3/31/2018   4/27/2018   Apr-18
4/28/2018   5/25/2018   May-18
5/26/2018   6/29/2018   Jun-18
6/30/2018   7/27/2018   Jul-18
7/28/2018   8/24/2018   Aug-18
8/25/2018   9/28/2018   Sep-18
9/29/2018   10/26/2018  Oct-18
10/27/2018  11/23/2018  Nov-18
11/24/2018  12/28/2018  Dec-18
12/29/2018  1/25/2019   Jan-19
1/26/2019   2/22/2019   Feb-19
2/23/2019   3/29/2019   Mar-19
3/30/2019   4/26/2019   Apr-19
4/27/2019   5/24/2019   May-19
5/25/2019   6/28/2019   Jun-19
```

Comment: The groupings are right there in the code but as far as a defined formula for each month - I don't know, that's why im hard-coding it.

Comment: It actually does though, the first argument to each IF statement is date range and the second argument is the desired output.

Comment: Why do the numbers keep doing down one from year to year? Will that continue to happen? I.E. will Jan 2020 be 12/28/2020 - 1/24/2020?

Comment: I do not have a pre-defined mathematical formula for the grouping of dates into financial months and therefore need to hard-code it. As far as I know, groupings are defined arbitrarily by hand.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of proper syntax for this use-case? If it is a matter of syntax then i'm not fussed about finding a more elegant solution - i'm happy to brute-force this one.

Comment: would you please confirm the following: the `formula` has a different `date format` that the `table`, which one is the correct one?, also the formula indicates that the `date` in cell 'D2' is a `text` not a `serial date`, which `format date` should be used?, is this also the default `format date` of your system?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in your table is:

1. The last Friday in each month is the month cut off, which means....
2. The last Saturday in each month is the start of the next month

---

This will take a input, verify that it is a date, and see if the date is before, equal to, or after the last Friday in the input month.

1. If before, `CSTMonth = Inputs Month`
2. If equal, `CSTMonth = Inputs Month`
3. If after, `CSTMonth = Month after Inputs Month`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CSTMonth(Target As Range)

If IsDate(Target) Then

  Dim LastDay As Date: LastDay = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Target, 0)
  Dim LastFri As Date: LastFri = LastDay - (Weekday(LastDay + 1) Mod 7)

    If Target <= LastFri Then
        CSTMonth = Format(Target, "MMM-YY")
    Else
        CSTMonth = Format(LastDay + 1, "MMM-YY")
    End If

End If

End Function
```

---

The benefit of finding the pattern in your table is that this will never need to be updated with *`brute force`*. Taking your approach would mean hard coding each and every months start and end dates.

Comment: My use of IF syntax was not in the context of a UDF but rather an inline IF statement in excel.

Comment: Hi, I have been informed that the pattern of financial months ending on the last Friday of each month is unfortunately not how our months are defined, they are ambiguously defined by our parent company. Sometimes they take a 4-4-5 week cycle, sometimes they don't. As a result, a hard-code method is needed.

Assuming that I have a table of every month-end date - how can I hardcode this in VBA?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a table with the starting dates for each period the try the following:

Assuming the table with the period starting dates is located at `B2:D25` and the dates are located at `F2:F25` and `J2:J25`

Enter this formula to obtain the Financial Period as date serial in `G2` then copy it to `G3:G25` and `K2:K25`:

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,$B$2:$D$25,3,1)
```

Enter this formula to obtain the Financial Period as text in `H2` then copy it to `H3:H25` and `L2:L25`:

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP(F3,$B$2:$D$25,3,1),"mmm-yyyy")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the complications you are facing but to get the desired results per your table, you can also use a simpler formula like

`=TEXT(EOMONTH(A2,1),"YY-MMM")`

OR

`=EOMONTH(A2,1)`
and format the cell in `yy-mmm` format.

where `A2` holds the start date.